# how to verify if joomla makes a query update to a field in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I've done this script and added on joomla mod_login after login on welcome message:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query= "UPDATE #__users SET piva=' . $user->partitaiva; .' where id=' . $user->id;";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

I've:
defined lines before `$user->partitaiva` and `$user->id`.
added field `piva` on `jos_users`.

There's no error, but nothing is written in db!

Could someone tell me how can i see if this works? a output error, or report...something!

thank you
S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the query, it must be

```
$query= " UPDATE #__users SET ".$db->nameQuote('piva')."=". $db->Quote($user->partitaiva) ."  where ".$db->nameQuote('id')." = ". $db->Quote($user->id);
```

Comment: And you must use object of JFactory::getUser() to make any changes for User.

Comment: how can i add an if piva value already exist -> don't write it again?

Comment: For your new new field you need to add an fiva variable to JUser Class. then get the object from $user = JFactory::getUser(); then check if(isset($user->fiva) && !empty($user->fiva)){....}